# wkhtmltopdf -> Issue to FIT Html table in A4 (C#)

Tags: c#, html, pdf-generation

Today i would your help on an issue i have when i generate my Html / Table in .pdf

I tried with Table to : width: 842px; height: 595px; (witch is A4 size), it doesn't fit.

So i tried with Table to : 1122px / 794px (witch is A4 too), but still doesn't fit..

If i use Width:100%, Height is not good. 
If i use Width: 100% and Height:100% too, still not good...

So, i'm asking your help :)

Print is on A4 Landscape mode.

(our backend is under C#)

Comment: Please show some your effort means what you did